# How to filter a table stored in S3 with over 1 billon rows using Dask or another Python library?

Tags: python, dataframe, amazon-s3, dask, parquet

I have a huge table (df1, ~1.5 billion rows) stored in a S3 bucket, divided in multiple parts or partitions with the Parquet extension. My goal is to filter it by keeping those rows where the value of a particular column exists in a column (with the same name) of another table (df2). I'm using Dask for this operation since the first table/DataFrame doesn't fit into memory.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
df1 = dd.read_parquet(f"s3://{MY_BUCKET}/{PATH_TO_HUGE_TABLE}/*", index=INDEX_COL)
df2 = dd.read_parquet(f"s3://{MY_BUCKET}/{PATH_TO_AUX_TABLE}/*", index=INDEX_COL, columns=A_SINGLE_COLUMN_LIST)

filtered_df1 = df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='inner')
filtered_df1 = filtered_df1.reset_index(drop=False)
filtered_df1.to_parquet(f"s3://{MY_BUCKET}/{PATH}", write_index=False)
```

The code above runs without problems till the workers start running out of memory and eventually the execution is aborted. I'm working with a quite powerful machine of 96 CPUs and more that 700GB of memory (and yet the huge table doesn't fit). I've tried to run it with 96 and 8 workers, but it happens the same in both cases.

I've also tried the following and then included the isin() method in a map_partitions() function. Both approaches had the same outcome that I explained above.

```
df2 = dd.read_parquet(f"s3://{MY_BUCKET}/{PATH_TO_AUX_TABLE}/*")
filter_values = df2[INDEX_COL].unique().compute()  # len(filter_values) --> ~17e6

df1 = dd.read_parquet(f"s3://{MY_BUCKET}/{PATH_TO_HUGE_TABLE}/*")
filtered_df1 = df1[ df1[INDEX_COL].isin(filter_values) ]
filtered_df1.to_parquet(f"s3://{MY_BUCKET}/{PATH}", write_index=False)
```

Does anyone know another way of doing this with Dask that could work? Perhaps a different Python library? Any idea is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: One strategy that could help (though you would need to change your huge table), would be to partition your huge data on the filter column.  Then you would have `s3://{MY_BUCKET}/{PATH_TO_HUGE_TABLE}/{FILTER_COLUMN}=0/`, `s3://{MY_BUCKET}/{PATH_TO_HUGE_TABLE}/{FILTER_COLUMN}=1/`, ...  Multiple tools understand this Hive partition format which can help you read only the data you need.  Not sure if it's reasonable for you to rewrite your big dataset though ‍♀️

Comment: Thank you for the reply @KyleParsons , but I don't think that works for me.

Comment: How big is df2? If it's small enought you could do the filtering while loading the data using the `isin` filter `read_parquet(..., filters=ds.filter('col1').isin(['value1', 'value2'])`. See https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.dataset.Expression.html#pyarrow.dataset.Expression

Comment: Hi @0x26res thanks for the reply. That looks interesting, however the list that I'd use in the isin() method has over 17 million values. I could try but I don't think it is small enough.

Comment: Could you perform the filter in Athena instead of Dask with Python?  Athena works nicely when it works, but for some large datasets it just kinda falls over.  Also how big are the constituent files for your large dataset?  Athena will likely have a nicer time running on top of your data if your files aren't too small.  I _think_ files should be GB sized not MB say.

Comment: For something this large I think looking at AWS's tools like Redshift might be worthwhile. You can [copy data from parquet to Redshift directly](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-usage_notes-copy-from-columnar.html).

Comment: I'll take a look a Athena @KyleParsons , but the size of the file is between 30-100MB.

Comment: I'll consider this alternative, thanks @MichaelDelgado

Comment: Just FYI I'm a huge fan of dask and usually err on the side of over-using it when other tools will do better. But for a larger-than-memory-to-larger-than-memory join like this I've found that an army of google/amazon/microsoft engineers can build better distributed query tools than I can trying to hack something together in dask ;) good luck and if you do figure this out be sure to report back!!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a [large to small join](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-joins.html#large-to-small-joins).    `df1` has 1.5 billion rows and `df2` has 17 million rows.

This might help:

```py
pdf2 = df2.compute()

filtered_df1 = df1.merge(pdf2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='inner')
```

If you could, please add some more info about `filtered_df1` like `npartitions` and `memory_usage`.  This seems like a solvable issue.